# Rails App not serving asset in production mode with custom assets folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

It works find under development mode, But show me the `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js"):` error in production mode.

Before running rails server, I ran `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace`

I added two assets folders under vendor

in  `application.rb` file , I insert thie line

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/themes"
```

And changed the `config.serve_static_assets` to `true`

```
+++ b/config/environments/production.rb
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@ DqaStreesfulServer::Application.configure do
   # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

   # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
-  config.serve_static_assets = false
+  config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Folder  Structure

```
vendor
├── assets
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
└── themes
    ├── ace-admin-theme
    │   ├── avatars
    │   ├── css
    │   ├── font
    │   ├── images
    │   ├── img
    │   └── js
    └── lenord-single-page-theme
        ├── css
        ├── fonts
        ├── img
        ├── index.html
        ├── js
        └── rs-assets
```

---

### UPDATE

I reference my js file in that way

```
welcome.html.haml
60:  %script{src:  asset_path("lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js")}
```

### UPDATE

I guess the problem may in `production.rb`

I tried to get all files to be compiled by adding this line in `production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/themes/* )
```

And I ran the server in production mode by `rails s -e production` command rather than `nginx or apache`

### UPDATE

I got `ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"` in production mode
After I did the following changes.

In `../../config/environments/production.rb`

```
+  config.assets.compile = true
+  config.assets.precompile = [/^[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\..*/]
+  config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )
```

I showed the treeview between vendoe/theme/ and public/assets here

Is it reasonable ?

under public/assets

```
% tree lenord-single-page-theme                                                                                                                               (git)-[feature/prettier_form] 
lenord-single-page-theme
└── js
    ├── application-dfabb3389cb2e71ba110a8589e5e106b.js
    └── application-dfabb3389cb2e71ba110a8589e5e106b.js.gz
```

under vendor/themes/

```
lenord-single-page-theme
├── css
│   ├── animate.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│   ├── prettyPhoto.css
│   ├── rs-settings-ie8.css
│   ├── rs-settings.css
│   └── style.css
├── fonts
│   ├── FontAwesome.otf
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff
├── img
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 10.jpg
│   ├── 11.png
│   ├── 12.jpg
│   ├── 13.png
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   ├── 3.jpg
│   ├── 4.png
│   ├── 5.png
│   ├── 6.png
│   ├── 8.jpg
│   ├── 9.jpg
│   ├── aboutus.png
│   ├── back-top.png
│   ├── banner_1.jpg
│   ├── banner_2.jpg
│   ├── banner_3.jpg
│   ├── blue-back.png
│   ├── dummy.png
│   ├── fback.png
│   ├── portfolio
│   │   ├── 1.jpg
│   │   ├── 2.jpg
│   │   ├── 3.jpg
│   │   ├── 4.jpg
│   │   ├── 5.jpg
│   │   ├── 6.jpg
│   │   ├── 7.jpg
│   │   ├── 8.jpg
│   │   ├── 9.jpg
│   │   ├── tn1.jpg
│   │   ├── tn2.jpg
│   │   ├── tn3.jpg
│   │   ├── tn4.jpg
│   │   ├── tn5.jpg
│   │   ├── tn6.jpg
│   │   ├── tn7.jpg
│   │   ├── tn8.jpg
│   │   └── tn9.jpg
│   ├── prettyPhoto
│   │   ├── dark_rounded
│   │   │   ├── btnNext.png
│   │   │   ├── btnPrevious.png
│   │   │   ├── contentPattern.png
│   │   │   ├── default_thumbnail.gif
│   │   │   ├── loader.gif
│   │   │   └── sprite.png
│   │   ├── dark_square
│   │   │   ├── btnNext.png
│   │   │   ├── btnPrevious.png
│   │   │   ├── contentPattern.png
│   │   │   ├── default_thumbnail.gif
│   │   │   ├── loader.gif
│   │   │   └── sprite.png
│   │   ├── default
│   │   │   ├── default_thumb.png
│   │   │   ├── loader.gif
│   │   │   ├── sprite.png
│   │   │   ├── sprite_next.png
│   │   │   ├── sprite_prev.png
│   │   │   ├── sprite_x.png
│   │   │   └── sprite_y.png
│   │   ├── facebook
│   │   │   ├── btnNext.png
│   │   │   ├── btnPrevious.png
│   │   │   ├── contentPatternBottom.png
│   │   │   ├── contentPatternLeft.png
│   │   │   ├── contentPatternRight.png
│   │   │   ├── contentPatternTop.png
│   │   │   ├── default_thumbnail.gif
│   │   │   ├── loader.gif
│   │   │   └── sprite.png
│   │   ├── light_rounded
│   │   │   ├── btnNext.png
│   │   │   ├── btnPrevious.png
│   │   │   ├── default_thumbnail.gif
│   │   │   ├── loader.gif
│   │   │   └── sprite.png
│   │   └── light_square
│   │       ├── btnNext.png
│   │       ├── btnPrevious.png
│   │       ├── default_thumbnail.gif
│   │       ├── loader.gif
│   │       └── sprite.png
│   ├── product.png
│   ├── service
│   │   ├── 11.png
│   │   ├── 12.png
│   │   ├── 21.png
│   │   ├── 22.png
│   │   ├── 31.png
│   │   ├── 32.png
│   │   ├── 41.png
│   │   └── 42.png
│   ├── service.png
│   ├── vast.jpg
│   ├── vivotek_square_icon.jpg
│   ├── vvtk_sd.jpg
│   └── wood-back.png
├── index.html
├── js
│   ├── application.js
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   ├── custom.js
│   ├── gmaps.js
│   ├── html5shiv.js
│   ├── jquery.arbitrary-anchor.js
│   ├── jquery.js
│   ├── jquery.knob.js
│   ├── jquery.prettyPhoto.js
│   ├── jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js
│   ├── jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js
│   ├── respond.min.js
│   └── waypoints.min.js
└── rs-assets
    ├── arrow_large_left.png
    ├── arrow_large_right.png
    ├── arrow_left.png
    ├── arrow_left2.png
    ├── arrow_right.png
    ├── arrow_right2.png
    ├── arrowleft.png
    ├── arrowright.png
    ├── arrows.psd
    ├── black50.png
    ├── boxed_bgtile.png
    ├── bullet.png
    ├── bullet_boxed.png
    ├── bullets.png
    ├── bullets.psd
    ├── bullets2.png
    ├── coloredbg.png
    ├── grain.png
    ├── large_left.png
    ├── large_right.png
    ├── loader.gif
    ├── loader2.gif
    ├── navigdots.png
    ├── navigdots_bgtile.png
    ├── shadow1.png
    ├── shadow2.png
    ├── shadow3.png
    ├── small_arrows.psd
    ├── small_left.png
    ├── small_left_boxed.png
    ├── small_right.png
    ├── small_right_boxed.png
    ├── timer.png
    ├── timerdot.png
    ├── transparent.jpg
    └── white50.png

14 directories, 154 files
```

Comment: How are you referencing the custom.js file in your view?

Comment: Try using `javascript_include_tag("lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js")`

Comment: `rake assets: precompile` worked fine?

Comment: @RoR yes, `rake assets: precompile` works

Comment: `%script{src:  asset-data-url("lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js")}` try this

Comment: @Iceman more worse, I got `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/%3Cscript%20src=%22/javascripts/lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E"):`

Comment: You have to use `= javascript_include_tag("lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js")` in your haml file

Comment: @Iceman I used  `= javascript_include_tag("lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js")` GOT `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js"):`

Comment: What does your production.rb look like, it's not adding the digest to the file name.

Comment: Have u tried asset-data-url?

Comment: @Iceman @RoR Hi, here is my `production.rb` https://gist.github.com/poc7667/50059c81b8cb70efd4d8

Comment: I updated my post again.

Comment: Here is the code for precompiling all assets. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: @Iceman I did some changes, but there is another problem, I updated my post, thanks~ I think the root cause is those assets folder is not in appropriate path, and still didn't be compiled ?

Comment: I'm not on my workstation right now, but if I remember correctly you need to provide every folder to config.assets.paths, that is, Rails doesn't recursively look in the sub-folders of your vendor folder

Comment: you can see the paths rails is using in the console (rails c), by typing `config.assets.paths` there

Comment: have you added in application.js tree like `//= require js_path`

Comment: write whatever your path is in place of js_path

Comment: @RoR No, I didn't. but will it be different in production mode and development mode ? I updated it you can refer  `https://gist.github.com/poc7667/50059c81b8cb70efd4d8`

Comment: if you have put it inside `application.html.erb` its fine...and no it will not be different when you will run `rake assets:pipeline` it will automatically adjust itself for production mode

Comment: every `javascript` should be in the `application.js` tree to take effect..or if you write it inside `application.html.erb` that will also work.. i think `application.js` tree is not able to find the `javascript` file you want.

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations: *app/assets*, *lib/assets* or *vendor/assets*.
You have placed your assets in *vendor/assets* and *vendor/themes*.

**Precompile additional assets:**

```
config.assets.precompile += ['vendor/themes/lenord-single-page-theme/js/*.js']
config.assets.precompile += ['vendor/themes/lenord-single-page-theme/css/*.css']
```

**Run the rake task:**

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

**Check under *public/assets*:**

That file should be precompiled in

> *vendor/themes/lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js*

OR

> *lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js*

**Then call the custom asset file like this:**

> javascript_include_tag "PATH_OF_THE_ASSET"

**Ex:**

> javascript_include_tag "lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js"

OR

> javascript_include_tag
>   "vendor/themes/lenord-single-page-theme/js/custom.js"